# Rails 6, Letter_opener_web: I cannot send email in rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I configured letter_opener_web and call Mailer in the controller.
But when I trigger the action and check letter_opener, nothing happens.
So I changed the method in controller to "deliver!" from  "deliver"

```
RelationshipMailer.follow_mail(@followed_user).deliver!
```

The following error shows up.

```
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
```

Actually, I configured the development.rb with

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener_web
```

What can I do? Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

delivery method is wrong

must be like this

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

`letter_opener_web` is not a delivery method which you used

Comment: I edited as you said. Error is still the same "Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25"